# Mouse flickering between guest and host on Vsphere client

Tags: mouse, vmware, vsphere

I am running vsphere 6.0 and my mouse flickers between guest and host. Only in one corner of my console is alright. My mouse flickers between the hand and the guests mouse. I have tried reinstalling and using more basic OS but no results.

Comment: Have you installed VMWare Tools on your guest OS? This will usually resolve the mouse flicker problem.

Comment: Yes i have but still no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a number of fixes:

- The internet connection
- How you installed the Host

Try reinstalling the Host.